# How to put NA in a stored list of a For loop when no result

Tags: r, for-loop

I've created a For loop to apply different models on a lot of variables :

```
my_data <- read.xlsx("phyla.xlsx")
start_variables <- 6
variables <- variable.names(my_data)
variables <- variables[-c(1:(start_variables-1))]

#make a list of data frame for each variable
DF.ls <- list()
for (i in start_variables:length(my_data)){
 DF.ls[[i]] <- data.frame(Sample_ID=my_data$Sample_ID,Genotype=my_data$Genotype, 
               Substrate=my_data$Substrate, y=my_data[[i]])
}
DF.ls <- DF.ls[-1]; DF.ls <- DF.ls[-1]; DF.ls <- DF.ls[-1]; DF.ls <- DF.ls[-1]; DF.ls <- DF.ls[-1]

#model1
model1.ls <- list()
for (i in 1:length(DF.ls)){
 model1.ls[[i]] <- gls(y~Substrate+Genotype+Substrate:Genotype, data=DF.ls[[i]])
}
AIC_model1_ls <- list()
for (i in 1:length(model1.ls)){
 AIC_model1_ls[[i]] <- AIC(summary(model1.ls[[i]]))
}
AIC_model1 = unlist(AIC_model1_ls)
AIC_model1 = rbind(AIC_model1)

#model2
model2.ls <- list()
for (i in 1:length(DF.ls)){
 model2.ls[[i]] <- gls(y~Substrate+Genotype+Substrate:Genotype, weights=varIdent(form=~1|Substrate), data=DF.ls[[i]])
}
AIC_model2_ls <- list()
for (i in 1:length(model2.ls)){
AIC_model2_ls[[i]] <- AIC(summary(model2.ls[[i]]))
}
AIC_model2 = unlist(AIC_model2_ls)
AIC_model2 = rbind(AIC_model2)
```

It may not be the best way to make it but it works just fine, except for when there are some treatments with zeros.

So my problem is that I have this error that occurs when there are zeros :

*Error in gls(y ~ Substrate + Genotype + Substrate:Genotype, weights = varIdent(form = ~1 | : false convergence (8)*

I'd like my For loop to put a NA in my list when this error occurs instead of nothing. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `try` function. This will capture an error without stopping your program. Here is an example since you did not provide a reproducible example:

```
# This model will fail since we have not assigned values to x and y
model <- try(lm(x ~ y), silent = TRUE)

# However check the output
model

> model
[1] "Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'x' not found\n"
attr(,"class")
[1] "try-error"
attr(,"condition")
<simpleError in eval(predvars, data, env): object 'x' not found>
```

If you pass something valid to try you see that you will get the proper result

```
model <- try(lm(wt~ mpg, data = mtcars))

model

> model

Call:
lm(formula = wt ~ mpg, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          mpg  
     6.0473      -0.1409
```

So with this in mind you could augment your code to do something like:

```
fit <- try(gls(y~Substrate+Genotype+Substrate:Genotype, weights=varIdent(form=~1|Substrate), data=DF.ls[[i]]), silent = TRUE)

if(class(fit)=="try-error"){
  model1.ls[[i]] <- NA
} else {
  model1.ls[[i]] <- fit
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked for my list of models! But now I have an other problem...

When I try to make a list of the AIC contained in the summaries of those models, it stops at the NA put in the previous list. How can I put NA in that list instead of applying the command?

> AIC_model2_ls <- list()
> for (i in 1:length(model2.ls)){
   AIC_model2_ls[[i]] <- AIC(summary(model2.ls[[i]]))
}
Error in UseMethod("logLik") : 
  no applicable method for 'logLik' applied to an object of class "c('summaryDefault', 'table')"

Comment: Wrap those functions in `try` too. Or another options is `if(is.na(model[I]){next(I)} ` so that if it sees NA it skips the rest of the steps and goes to the next value of i

Comment: Actually I want it to put another NA in that new list when it encounters NA. I wrote this : `AIC_model2_ls[i] <- ifelse(is.na(model2.ls[[i]]), NA, AIC(summary(model2.ls[[i]])))`